# How can I get Firebug to step-through inline javascript code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

When my javascript code is contained in a HEAD block in my HTML file, it seems I can't set a breakpoint on it to debug it.

How can I do this?

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/mhmbha.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/mhmbha.png)

this is what I see under the script tag:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/17g116c.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/17g116c.png)

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/irki5p.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/irki5p.png)

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/mts9hn.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/mts9hn.png)

**Odd: when I take the javascript block OUT of my HTML `<head>` area, then the .htm page appears under scripts (kind of counter-productive):**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/5rfia.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/5rfia.png)

**ok, the only solution I can find to this question is to put my HEAD scripts back into a .js file, anyone have a way to debug inline javascript?**

Answer (score 4):

You should search for your code in the *Script* tab, you can't set breakpoints in the *HTML* tab.

[image]

**Edit**: In your second screenshot, you are looking the code of the Google JS API file, you can either, change the file manually (*the red square at left on my screenshot*), or use the search-box at the right:

[image: firebug search]

Comment: i normally debug on .js files, and that is how I do it, but now I've got javascript in an html file and can't find my inline textblock under script, screenshot above.

Comment: I search for "fadeIn" in the search box and it can't find it

Comment: your screenshot is helpful but I'm not finding "dom.js" anywhere under script or on the main firebug header line, something I need to do to get that to appear?

Answer (score 4):

Enclose your functions in javascript with

```
debugger;
function blah
debugger;
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't seem to bring it up anywhere I can find it

Answer (score 4):

#### I found the problem.

instead of:

```
if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
```

I had:

```
if($(this).next().is(':hidden') {
```

i.e. the missing end-parenthesis was causing the javascript file (or .htm page including the javascript) not to show up under firebug "scripts".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set breakpoints from the "HTML" tab in firebug.

Click over to the "script" tab, and find your script in the lower dropdown list, and you should be able to set a breakpoint from there.

Comment: under the script tag I see "all" and "jsapi", under those I don't see "dom.js" or anything that contains my code, searching for "fadeIn" in the searchbox on the right doesn't find my code

Answer (score 0):

2016: Firefox, press F12, go to Debugger, look for your page (not a .js script)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger